# How to add easing to continuous animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, math

I have the following JSFiddle, where by using `requestAnimationFrame`, an element is continually bouncing against the edges of its container along the x axis; https://jsfiddle.net/anhd08so/

Basically, on each frame, I add the defined velocity (`vx`) to the position (`x`). Then I check whether the new position is out of bounds, and if so, I set to the minimum value, and invert the `vx` to make it go the other way.

```
var x = 50;
var vx = 5;

var step = function(){
  x = x + vx;

  if(x < 0) {
    x = 1;
    vx = Math.abs(vx);
  } else if(x > 400) {
    x = 400;
    vx = -Math.abs(vx);
  }

  el.css("left", x);
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
};
```

This works, but the change of direction is really sudden, and not realistic. I want to add easing so that the element slows down gradually as it approaches the edge, and accelerates again in the other direction.

I tried to do this with something like `vx = vx - vx * 0.3` replacing the `Math.abs`, and while it does slow it down, it never again gains the equal amount of inverse velocity when it goes the other way.

This would of course be a piece of cake with CSS transitions/keyframes, but my use case requires defining the motion frame by frame in code.

How can I add easing to this motion, so that the element changing direction looks more realistic?

Comment: Why not use a sine function? For example, `var t = 0; var step = function() { var x = Math.floor(Math.cos(t)*198+200.5); t += 0.03; /*...*/ }`

Comment: That looks a lot more promising! What are 198 and 200.5 in relation to, in case the stage or item are a different size?

Comment: Well, a sine function (or cosine, in this case) varies between -1 and +1. So if you want to cover the range from -200 to +200, you should multiply it by 200 (so it covers the range -200 to +200), then add 200 (giving you the range from 0 to 400). I dropped the multiplier slightly because the bar you're moving has a width of 2px and will overlap the  ends of the enclosing rectangle if you stick to an amplitude of 200. But you can put in whatever numbers you like. The value 0.03 affects the speed of the movement. Change it to 0.06 and the animation will be twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE #1**

Here you are https://jsfiddle.net/anhd08so/64/

Notice that there is a `translateX` is used instead of `left`. It's better to use transforms if you want to have smoother animations. Otherwise browser may get slow due to re-rendering when you change `left` or similar.

Instead of `ease-in-out` you may use some custom cubic-bezier animations.

Review the code. Ask me if you have any question.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('p');

function toggleDirection() {
 var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("transform");
  var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style);
  
  if (matrix.e === 50) {
   el.classList.add('p--right');
  } else {
   el.classList.remove('p--right');
  } 
}

el.addEventListener("transitionend", toggleDirection);

window.onload = toggleDirection();
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  /* left: 50px; */
  transform: translateX(50px);
  width: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #111;
  
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
  
  will-change: transform;
}

.p--right {
  transform: translateX(350px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does look like it would need a lot more breakpoints and a lot of manual testing to get it looking natural, though. I'm sure there's a mathematical way to do this dynamically, but I can't figure out how to apply it.

Comment: Try to use jQuery `.animate()` it can apply some easing including some that you could find in the Internet where you apply your own behaviour. It will change `x` from one state to another one with easing. In your example to `400`(think how to make a loop). Also, there is a `Velocity.js` library which uses `requestAnimationframe`. So it will be better for browser.

Comment: One minute. I'll try to make similar to yours using css

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:
Declare modifier outside the step function:

```
var modifier = 1;
```

And then at the start of the step, you just calculate the modifier like so:

```
if ( x<=200) {
    modifier = Math.max(0.1 , ( x / 200));
} else {
    modifier = Math.max(0.1 , ( (200-(x % 200)) / 200));
}
x = x + modifier * vx;
```

So what you are doing, is basically calculating how far it is from the midpoint ( 400/ 2 = 200), and then adjusting the velocity.

like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/anhd08so/71/

Comment: Of corse you an always adjust the speed and declare the 200 as a global variable. Plus math.max is just there so it does not go down to 0 speed